# How to get all results from multiple columns in a single column - SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, union, window-functions

I want to get all the results in 2 of my columns together.

I have a table `my_table` like:

```
colA    colB
a       e 
b       e 
c       f
d       g
```

Intended output:

```
id      letter
1       a       
2       b       
3       c       
4       d       
5       e 
6       f 
7       g
```

I know this is achievable with `UNION` but I'm a bit confused about how the numbering would work then. I'm good with a solution without `UNION` too. The order of `letter` in the output also doesn't matter, but each value needs a unique ID.

What I tried:

```
SELECT 
     row_number() OVER (ORDER BY letter) AS id,
     colA AS letter
FROM my_table
UNION
SELECT
     row_number() OVER (ORDER BY letter) AS id,
     colB AS letter
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY letter) AS id, *
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT colA AS letter
     FROM my_table
     UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT colB AS letter
     FROM my_table
)
```

Comment: You should try playing with the data and seeing for yourself -- try doing something like `order by letter desc` and think about what happens when you do that. Also, documentation is your best friend, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15